# How can I see console output from standalone qml application?

Tags: qt, debugging, qml

I have some issues deploying a qml application on Windows; after including the required dll's with the standalone executable, the application works fine on the computer from which the app was developed. The app will launch on other computers, but the content is blank.

In response, I want to find the problem(s) by debugging with "QML_IMPORT_TRACE" and other console outputs (console.log()). This works fine when I run the app from QtCreator. How can I show the same output when running the executable (shipped with dlls) from another computer? Is it possible from cmd in some way?

Comment: Which dlls do you ship with your app?

Comment: You can use debugview to see outputs from console.log: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Comment: What happens if you launch it directly from the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `config += console` to your .pro-File should open a seperate console with the outputs.
You also need to run qmake.