# OnClicked event doesn't work in QML window

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've created a simple QML window with a map and a marker on it. But there is no reaction on a mouse click. The Window is opened from C++ application made in Qt 6.5.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtLocation
import QtPositioning

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Карта")

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 14
        Component.onCompleted: console.log("Text onCompleted map.")

        MouseArea {
            id: m1
            anchors.fill: parent
            //propagateMouseEvent: true
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
            onClicked: console.log("click ")

            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "transparent"
                border.color: "black"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Window` is opened from C++

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine);
    QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true);
    component.loadUrl(QUrl("map.qml"));
    if (component.isReady())
        component.create();
    else
        qWarning() << component.errorString();
}
```

Comment: I've tested it with Qt 5.15.11 and 6.5.0-beta1 and it works. When I click on the map the Application Output panel in QtCreator shows `qml: click `. What are you using to run the application?

Comment: I am using Qt 6.5.

Comment: I've also used Qt 6.5.0 (well it is 6.5.0-beta) which is available via the maintainance tool. How did you get your version of Qt? Did you compile it yourself? How do you run your application? What operating system? Are there any other outputs? If you think it is a bug report it here: https://bugreports.qt.io/

Comment: Not, I haven't compiled it by myself. OS -Windows 11. This Window is opened from C++ app, here is the code
`void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine);
    QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true);
    component.loadUrl(QUrl("map.qml"));
    if ( component.isReady() )
        component.create();
    else
        qWarning() << component.errorString();
}`

Comment: Could you try to use the Qt 6.5.0-beta1? It could be that something in your custom build Qt is missing.

Comment: Yes, it's 6.5-beta1.

Comment: sorry, didn't read your reply properly.

Comment: Did you try opening the QML-view from a different spot than the on_pushButton_2_clicked handler?

Comment: I have just opened it directly from main.cpp - and everything is ok, it reacts on mouse clicks. Thanks, that is something to start with, but I still want to open it on button pressed...

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it on Linux and everything works. I remember someone saying that on Windows the QML output is special. It seems you need to use [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview). Have a look at the comment on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222704/how-can-i-see-console-output-from-standalone-qml-application). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72304878/deployed-qt-qml-application-dont-show-any-window) one as well.

---

**Edit:** @Amfasis comment made me look again at your push button clicked slot implementation. The issue is that you create instances of `QQmlEngine` and `QQmlComponent` in the slot that get destroyed when leaving the function. You are creating an object which will be automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope. You should create an object dynamically. This way, the object you created will not be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

A quick fix would be to use pointers, but keep in mind that in the solution below the created pointers aren't reachable anymore after the function finished resulting in memory leaks. You should store them as members of your `MainWindow`.

```
void MainWindow::onPushButtonClicked()
{
    QQmlEngine *engine = new QQmlEngine;
    QQmlComponent *component = new QQmlComponent(engine);
    QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true);
    component->loadUrl(QUrl("main.qml"));
    if (component->isReady())
        component->create();
    else
        qWarning() << component->errorString();
}
```

Comment: I have tried DebugView, but there is no message there either. Only the massage "Text onCompleted map."

Comment: Did you get that output also without DebugView?

Comment: Yes, I see it in my Qt output tab.

Comment: Ok, then the output was never the problem. Could you try to show the click/pressed state differently by doing something like this `border.color: m1.pressed ? "red" : "black` to the `Rectangle` on top? Maybe increase the `border.width`. Is it changing when pressing on the map?

Comment: The color doesn't change.

Comment: Could you try to set `z:100` ([z : real](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop)) on the `MouseArea`? It could be that the stacking order is wrong and the map receives the mouse events.

Comment: The same result...

Comment: I just installed Qt6.5.0-beta and see "clicked " appearing in Qt Creator when I click on the map. Having said that,, I have observed on some touch-screen devices, there could be a problem with gesture handling, particularly when both Map and MouseArea are both vying for mouse input.

Comment: @Slejpnir I've edited my answer. It is a matter of `QQmlEngine` and `QQmlComponent` getting destroyed, because going out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Qt6.5.0-beta and see "clicked " appearing in Qt Creator when I click on the map. Having said that, I have observed on some touch-screen devices, there could be a problem with gesture handling, particularly when both Map and MouseArea are both vying for mouse input.

If that is what's happening, it may worth considering TapHandler, e.g.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtLocation
import QtPositioning

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Карта")

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 14
        Component.onCompleted: console.log("Text onCompleted map.")

        TapHandler {
            onTapped: console.log("TAPPED")
        }
    }
}
```